# Transition Alternative to Android Prior API 19

Tags: android, textarea

I'm developing an app, and I need to animate some simple stuff, I manage to did it by using the Transition Framework, however it is not supported in android versions prior KITKAT(API LEVEL 19), I would like to know some alternatives to make some simple transitions in older devices, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following libraries:

- [TransitionsBackport](https://github.com/guerwan/TransitionsBackport)
- [transitions-everywhere](https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere)
- [SmoothTransition](https://github.com/dkmeteor/SmoothTransition)
- [PreLollipopTransition](https://github.com/takahirom/PreLollipopTransition)
- [android-transition](https://github.com/kaichunlin/android-transition)

Comment: Thank you, I used transitions-everywhere and it seems to work(It does not crash) however in older devices (Android 2.3) it reenders  the layout that is supposed to be animated with a darkbackground, why this is happening?